# No puedo asignar variable en Android con Firebase

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase

Estoy intentando hacer un método para comprobar si existe el email de un usuario, el cuál funciona, pero necesito hacer que me retorne una variable de tipo boolean.
Intenté declarando la variable fuera del método, pero cuando seteo su valor, no cambia. El toast funciona bien y me dice si existe o no existe conforme a mi tabla user, pero necesito retornar la variable para poder programarlo en un buttom en una activity y no permitir que el usuario registre otro email igual.

este es el método

```
    public boolean userExist(Context context){
    boolean exist=false;
    cn.initFirebase();
    Query q = cn.getReference().child("User").orderByChild("user_email").equalTo(u.getUser_email());
    q.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                //Toast.makeText(context, "Usuario existe", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                exist=true;
                }
            else{
               //Toast.makeText(context, "Usuario no existe", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                exist=false;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
    return  exist;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola deberias realizarlo mediante un interface, ya que la llamada es asyncrono, entonces tu le estas siempre le estas regresando falso :D, deberias crear tu interface, pasarlo como parametro de tu funcion y asi llamarlo, y tu clase que implemente UserExist implementar la interface :D PD:tu funcion seria un void simple :D

Comment: Excelente Carlos, asi es como deberia hacerse, ahi agregue la respuesta debajo , un saludo

Comment: Me funcionó con la respuesta de Gastón, pues no sabía como implementar la interfaz, ya que nunca había usado una, su explicación y detalle resolvió mi pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como sugiere carlos, deberias realizar una interfaz, con una interfaz podes saber teniendo una bandera dentro de `onDataChanged()` cuando termine de ejecutarse la llamada al servidor, y de esa forma llamar a un metodo en particular.

Primero creamos la interfaz

```
interface UserListener {

    void onUserExists(Boolean exists);
    void onUserFetchError(String error);
}
```

Luego, en tu metodo `userExists()` agregamos el listener

```
public userExist(Context context,UserListener listener){
    boolean exist=false;
    cn.initFirebase();
    Query q = cn.getReference().child("User").orderByChild("user_email").equalTo(u.getUser_email());
    q.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            listener.onUserExists(dataSnapshot.exists());
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
           listener.onUserFetchError(databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

De esta forma, cuando llames al metodo `userExist(...)` vas a necesitar pasarle un callback, que va a lanzarse cuando el metodo pueda retornar el `Boolean` con la interfaz o el `error` en su caso.

```
userExist(this,new UserListener() {

 @Override
public void onUserExists(Boolean exist) {
                //Aca podes hacer lo que quieras con el valor de exist
            }

 @Override
public void onUserFetchError(String error) {
                //Aca podes mostrar un Toast con el error
            }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

La llamadas a Firebase son asincronas, es decir se ejecuta la llamada pero la respuesta no se recibira de inmediato, la ejecucion seguirá, por lo tanto tu variable retorna false. puede intentar lo siguiente:

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
   miMetodo(dataSnapshot.exists()); //aqui va true o false si existe y solo se ejecuta hasta recibir una respuesta
    }
```

En otro metodo ejecutar lo que quieres hacer al recibir la respuesta

```
 private void miMetodo(booelan exist){
     if(exixst){
         //aqui ejecutas lo que deseas
      }
 }
```

Comment: Tene en cuenta que ese metodo va a retornar siempre falso a no ser que solo se llame cuando onDataChange() termine